# Adding MapServer layer in Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, mapserver, openlayers

As per i know that there is an API called Openlayers.MapServer in openlayers 2, which is used to show MapServer file in browser in openlayers. How can i add an MapServer file in Openlayers 3, as i read somewhere that Openlayers 3 is currently under development for an API of MapServer, but please help me to add MapServer file in Openlayers 3.

Comment: what is your wms url?

Comment: http://localhost:8081/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?mode=browse&template=openlayers&layers=all&map=C:/ms4w/apps/osm/basemaps/osm-google.map  this is my url which is working fine in browser but i want ot use it in openlayers 3.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/Alophind/5pSrJ/

Comment: Did you see the [examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/)? Filter with WMS.

Comment: The openlayers.org site has a good example already.  You can even turn it into a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 5):

There are two mode in MapServer in fact and it can be confusing for end users without knowledge about the project history.

- The first one, the now mostly outdated `mode cgi` (the url contains `mode=browse`) way where you don't rely on standards OGC webservices. It was supported in OpenLayers 2 by default because of history (more Mapserver instances not using WMS at this time). In the OpenLayers version 3, you will have to custom `ol.source.XYZ` but there are not built-in component.
  This is your case according to your provided URL http://localhost:8081/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?mode=browse&template=openlayers&layers=all&map=C:/ms4w/apps/osm/basemaps/osm-google.map
- The second case where you use MapServer WMS abilities. You always use cgi Mapserver but the WMS way (no `mode=browse`). In this case, support is working for both OpenLayers 2 and 3. You just need to rely on [the official samples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/) mentioned in the comments.

IMO, instead of fighting with configuration on OpenLayers side, just configure your Mapserver mapfile to support WMS http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html and then use the OpenLayers 3 WMS default support.